# Class is not key value coding-compliant for the key staticTexts

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

I have this error: `XCTAssertTrue failed: throwing "[<XCElementSnapshot 0x7fea978b1a10> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key staticTexts."`

Here is the code:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(self.staticTexts[%@].exists == true) AND (self.staticTexts[%@].exists == true)", message, nameString)
XCTAssert(app.collectionViews.childrenMatchingType(.Cell).elementMatchingPredicate(predicate).exists)
```

Error is thrown on the second line.

I have looked at other answers on SO with the same error, and it's mostly caused by having a variable of a different class, however I don't see the possibility for this error here. Also, I checked to see that the predicate is formatted correctly.

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: what type is `staticTexts` and what type is the parent class? A key value coding-compliant variable must be a property or must have explicit getter and setter methods.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that your `staticTexts` property is `dynamic` or otherwise available to objc (by marking it `@objc` for instance). Swift will not generate KVC-compliant accessors unless it thinks it needs to.

Alternately, use something other than `NSPredicate` here. Making a property dynamic when it's not needed has a performance cost, which is why Swift doesn't do it automatically. So marking it `dynamic` just so a unit test can access it may be a poor tradeoff.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the error goes away when I apply the predicate to static texts vs. the cells and then try to access the static texts inside the predicate. So for example,

```
let predicate = NSPredicate("self.title like %@", message)
app.descendantsMatchingType(.StaticText).elementMatchingPredicate(predicate).exists
```

would get rid of the error.